# Getting Data points for canvasjs from a text file

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

Im trying to make a chart that dynamically gets plot values from a .txt file.
Here i can produce a simple chart with canvasjs this is the exact kind of chart i need to make except for it should get x values from  a .txt file dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "Percents",
       fontFamily: "Impact",
        fontWeight: "normal"
      },

      legend:{
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        horizontalAlign: "center"
      },
      data: [
      {
        //startAngle: 45,
       indexLabelFontSize: 20,
       indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",
       indexLabelFontColor: "darkgrey",
      indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey",
       indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
       type: "doughnut",
       showInLegend: true,
       dataPoints: [
       {  y: 55, legendText:"55%", indexLabel: "55%" },
       {  y: 45, legendText:"45%", indexLabel: "45%" },
       ]
     }
     ]
   });

     chart.render();
   }
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script></head>
     <body>
       <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
       </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Here i try  but it fails

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var dataPoints = [];

//Replace text file's path according to your requirement.
$.get("MYFILE.txt", function(data) {
var x = 0;
var allLines = data.split('\n');
if(allLines.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0; i< allLines.length; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({x: x , y: parseInt(allLines[i])});
        x += .25;
    }
}
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{
        text: "Chart using Text File Data"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        dataPoints : dataPoints,
    }]
});
chart.render();
});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesnt even give me any errors to debug.

EDIT: Content of .TXT file is very simple

MYFILE.txt

```
56
```

Comment: What is the content of your MYFILE.txt?

Comment: And why are you loading canvasjs as well as jquery.canvasjs? Is this a requirement of canvasjs (I don't know the library)?

Comment: Here's a working jsfiddle with just the ajax request replaced by hardcoded fake data: https://jsfiddle.net/ye2yeers/ so it must be your ajax request that is failing. I can't see where you include jQuery in your markup? And are you sure that the file exists? Does the request show up in the network tab of your dev tools, and if so, what does it look like?

Comment: @connum I may have to take a trip back to the basics. i cant get any ajax or jquery working on Ubuntu. i even tried yours from google apis.

Comment: i was also trying to just read the file with javascript a put it in a variable

Comment: That cannot be an issue with your OS... How are you opening the files in your browser? Vie the file system (`file:///`) or on a (local) web server? Because ajax requests won't work when opening the HTML file from the file system.

Comment: @connum bingo you git me!!! All files are local ive been attempting to pull them straight from /var/www/html Directory as i do with anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this code, where I only replaced the ajax request by hardcoded data, is working, it has to be a problem with the ajax request itself.

```js
var dataPoints = [];

(function(data) {
  var x = 0;
  var allLines = data.split('\n');
  if(allLines.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i< allLines.length; i++) {
          dataPoints.push({x: x , y: parseInt(allLines[i])});
          x += .25;
      }
  }
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
      title :{
          text: "Chart using Text File Data"
      },
      data: [{
          type: "line",
          dataPoints : dataPoints,
      }]
  });
  chart.render();
})("1\n2\n4\n3");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

As we found out in the comments, it is as I assumed, that you are trying to run the files from the file system via `file:///` in your browser, instead of a (local) web server, but ajax requests are not executable in this environment for security reasons.